# Wordpress remove hyperlinks on parent menu item

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my php generated nav-menu I'd like to make parent items unclickable and not related to a page. I just want them to reveal children when hover.

PHP code generating the nav-menu:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?>
```

I'd need to remove the href link in any element that has "page_item_has_children" as class.

Can't use the "custum link" method because since my theme is made from scratch I don't have access to that wp setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save menu code in variable and remove all links through preg_replace.

```
$menu = wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=' );
$finalMenu = preg_replace('/(page_item_has_children.*?)<a href=\".*?\">(.*?)<\/a>/', '\\1\\2', $menu);
echo $finalMenu;
```

Comment: Great! However, the ≤/li> closing tag is missing, I'm very bad with regex and can't figure out where to put it. Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: Nevermind IT IS closing. Sorry. Thanks so much, you're a hero!!